# PostgreSQL Ordering Records in a Hierarchal Query Result

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchy, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to do something that should be simple but I'm missing something. I am trying to return some hierarchical data in grouped and ordered. a Rather than trying to explain, I am attaching a picture... heard they are worth a thousand words:

[image: Order of data in the database vs the order the resultset needs to be in.]

Note that hard coded values are no good because the main selection criteria will be the article_id, and then ordered along the lines of the first 'root level' article_comment_id for the article followed by its sub-nodes, then the next 'root level' article_comment_id and its sub-nodes.

I am providing a sample table and data so you can see what I mean, plus a screen capture showing what I am trying to achieve.

```
CREATE TABLE test_comment
(
  article_comment_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  article_id bigint NOT NULL,
  parent_comment_id bigint,
  comment text NOT NULL,
  comment_depth integer,
  CONSTRAINT test_comment_pkey PRIMARY KEY (article_comment_id )
)

INSERT INTO test_comment (article_comment_id, article_id, parent_comment_id, comment, comment_depth)
VALUES
 (1, 100, 0, 'First Root Comment', 0)
,(5, 100, 0, 'Second Root Comment', 0)
,(2, 100, 1, 'Reply 1 to Root Comment', 1)
,(3, 100, 2, 'Reply 2 to Reply 1', 2)
,(4, 100, 3, 'Reply 3 to Reply 2', 3)
,(6, 100, 2, 'Reply 4 to Reply 1', 2)
,(7, 100, 5, 'Reply 5 to Second Root Comment', 1);
```

I have tried this, but it does not provide the proper order:

```
with recursive comment_list(article_comment_id, parent_comment_id, comment, article_id) AS (
    select c.article_comment_id, c.parent_comment_id, c.comment, c.article_id
    from test_comment c
    where article_id = 100
  union
    select c.article_comment_id, c.parent_comment_id, c.comment, c.article_id
    from test_comment c, comment_list cl
    where c.article_comment_id = cl.article_comment_id
    )
    select * from comment_list;
```

And can this PostgreSQL specific query be used with JPA, anyway?

Comment: This data IS simlified. To whoever edited this so that there was only one record, one record doesn't make sense when you are trying to show a recursive hierarchical query.

Comment: Erwin changed the multiple INSERTs into a single insert that creates multiple rows. Makes the data easier to read without scrolling

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter Apologies, all I saw were the slashed out inserts... I didn't realize there was something added at the end.

Comment: @BillR: Actually I didn't "add" anything, just trim some noise. Since you seem to agree now, I rolled back to my edit and reapplied your minor fix. That's what the rollback is for ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to "carry" the root article id down to each node and calculate the hierarchy level to be able to get that ordering:

```
with recursive comment_list(article_comment_id, parent_comment_id, comment, article_id, level, root_id) AS (
    select c.article_comment_id, 
           c.parent_comment_id, 
           c.comment, 
           c.article_id, 
           0 as level,
           article_comment_id as root_id 
    from test_comment c
    where article_id = 100
      and parent_comment_id = 0

  union

    select c.article_comment_id, 
           c.parent_comment_id, 
           c.comment, 
           c.article_id, 
           cl.level + 1,
           cl.article_comment_id 
    from test_comment c
       join comment_list cl on c.parent_comment_id = cl.article_comment_id
)
select article_comment_id, 
     parent_comment_id, 
     comment, 
     article_id
from comment_list
order by root_id, level;
```

SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/af0d6/4

(Btw: you have your join wrong in the recursive part of the union)

Comment: You say carry the root, do you mean the root "article_comment_id"? You have "order by root_id, level;" but "root_id" is not defined anywhere.

Comment: @BillR: root_id **is** defined. I just forgot to include it in the column aliases in the `with ...` definition (but it was part of the inner SELECT)

Comment: is and forgot don't go together :D   I know your intent but I couldn't figure out which one you were meaning to alias. :) Thanks for the help and hope you don't mind the little kidding. 
When I run this (on my machine or sqlfiddle) it looks to correctly group under the "root" comment id. However it brings back 16 rows when 7 is expected. If someone can provide insight, please. In the meantime I'll also look at this.

Comment: @BillR: can you setup a SQLFiddle example to show the extra rows?

Comment: I click on the link and see them. You can compare to what I am trying to do with the image I posted in the question.... I'll post  an image below your answer of what I see in SQLFiddle to show a comparison. You can right click the image and select 'view image' to see better. Also, the level (comment_depth) is stored in the table itself. It is inserted with the record.

Comment: @BillR Your edit will probably not be approved. Here is the link to the image though http://i.stack.imgur.com/NKpWe.jpg. Just as a note, editing others post is supposed to be used to clear up formatting, spelling, and/or grammatical mistakes only.

Comment: @jschoen I don't see why it should be deleted because it is just a screen shot of what was linked to so that we don't have to page back and forth and shows what I see which might not be what he sees. And it relates directly to the answer, not to the question. It doesn't make sense to edit my question and add it there. If helping to clarify things is wrong, there is some serious misthinking going on.

Comment: @BillR I am not saying you are wrong, I actually clicked approve, but I think it takes 3 votes for it, and it already had 2 rejects. The problem is context, the review system does not give you that, so unless you click through like I did, it is easy to think it is an invalid edit. If  a_horse_with_no_name wants wants to edit it in though he can do that without having to have it approved.

Comment: @jschoen nice to know someone at least reads what they are affecting without dogmatism. :)

Comment: @BillR: it was a mistake in the select for the root nodes (it was missing the `where parent_comment_id = 0`. See my corrected solution

Comment: Awesome horse. Now I need to learn and grok this. I'll use it but I also think I'll try some variations to see if I can make it sink in better. This is a great feature but not really intuitive to use (to me) until it *is* understood...  :D.  Thanks again for your patience. BTW, do you know how well this works with JPA named queries (hibernate back end)? I'm thinking I going to have to write a native query for it. That part at least is not a big deal.

Comment: Now I am having issues grouping the final query. But I posted that as a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315410/postgres-group-by-query  .....